# Compilation error while using Method reference in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I am not understanding the reason, for having the compilation error for the below program. Where am I going wrong? I want to print the value of the string as output using method reference.

```
public class ConsumerDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("hello", (str)-> str::toUpperCase);
    }

    public static void test(String str, Consumer<String> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(str);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test("hello", String::toUpperCase)
```

should be the correct syntax.

In order to print the upper case of the input, you can use:

```
String str = "hello"; // any input value
test(str.toUpperCase(), System.out::println);
```

Comment: I want to print after converting to uppercase

Comment: Although this _compiles_ the result of `String::toUpperCase` will be ignored.

Comment: @Aomine agreed that's why wanted to know what OP was willing to perform with the consumer.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot combine lambda syntax and method reference syntax as such.

You're either looking for:

```
test("hello", String::toUpperCase);
```

or:

```
test("hello", s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

but this then means the result of `String::toUpperCase`/`s -> s.toUpperCase()` is ignored *hence*, you'll need to perform something more useful. for example:

```
test("hello", s -> System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()));
```